# ¿Por qué no se mueve el objeto en este juego de pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

Estoy desarrollando un juego con Pygame en el que tengo un rectángulo que representa a un jugador.
Sin embargo, estoy enfrentando un problema:
el rectángulo aparece en la pantalla del juego pero no se mueve cuando presiono las flechas del teclado.

Traté de imprimir los eventos para ver qué sucedía.
El juego sí capta cuando presiono alguna tecla pero, no sé por qué, no se mueve.
Aquí les muestro mi código.

```
import pygame

# Dimensiones de la pantalla del juego
ANCHO = 1000
ALTURA = 600

# Cuadros por segundo
CPS = 60

# Ventana del juego                                       
VENTANA = pygame.display.set_mode((ANCHO, ALTURA))   

# Mensaje de la pantalla del juego
pygame.display.set_caption("Juego de ping pong")

# Color de la pantalla (blanco)
COLOR_DE_FONDO = (255, 255, 255)

# Color de los jugadores
color_jugador_1 = (255, 0, 0)
color_jugador_2 = (10, 0, 255)


# Posicion inicial y tamaño de los jugadores
tamaño_pos_jugador_1 = (100,100,15,200)
tamaño_pos_jugador_2 = (900,300,15,200)

# Velocidad de los jugarores
velocidad_jugadores = 5


# Movimiento mediante teclas
def movimiento_jugador_1(teclas, tamaño_pos_jugador_1):
    tamaño_pos_jugador_1 = list(tamaño_pos_jugador_1)
    if teclas[pygame.K_UP]:
        tamaño_pos_jugador_1[1]-= velocidad_jugadores
    if teclas[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        tamaño_pos_jugador_1[1]+= velocidad_jugadores
    if teclas[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        tamaño_pos_jugador_1[0]-= velocidad_jugadores
    if teclas[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        tamaño_pos_jugador_1[0]+= velocidad_jugadores


# Dibuja los rectangulos en la pantalla
def dibujar_ventana(color_jugador_1, tamaño_pos_jugador_1, color_jugador_2, tamaño_pos_jugador_2):
    pygame.draw.rect(VENTANA, color_jugador_1, tamaño_pos_jugador_1)
    #pygame.draw.rect(VENTANA, color_jugador_2, tamaño_pos_jugador_2)


def main():
    # Inicializa los modulos de pygame
    pygame.init()   
    
    reloj = pygame.time.Clock()
  
    corriendo = True
    while corriendo:
    
        for evento in pygame.event.get():
            # Se verifica si el jugador cierra el juego
            if evento.type == pygame.QUIT:  
                
                # Se cierra el juego 
                corriendo = False
                break    
            
        # Se cambia el color de la pantalla
        VENTANA.fill(COLOR_DE_FONDO)
        
        # Se captura cuales teclas presiona el usuario
        teclas = pygame.key.get_pressed()         
            
        # Se mueve el rectangulo del jugador 1 ()
        movimiento_jugador_1(teclas, tamaño_pos_jugador_1)
        
        
        # Se dibujan los rectangulos de los jugadores
        dibujar_ventana(color_jugador_1, tamaño_pos_jugador_1, color_jugador_2, tamaño_pos_jugador_2)
        
        # Se actualiza la pantalla
        pygame.display.update()
        reloj.tick(CPS)       
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Cualquier ayuda es agradecida

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si depuras la función `movimiento_jugador_1`, verás que la variable `tamaño_pos_jugador_1` tiene el mismo valor antes y después de la llamada.
Esto no puede ser de otra forma ya que `tamaño_pos_jugador_1` es una [tupla](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuples) y las tuplas en Python son inmutables.
Si quieres cambiar `tamaño_pos_jugador_1`, tendrás que hacer una reasignación editando `movimiento_jugador_1` para que devuelva la tupla modificada:

```py
def movimiento_jugador_1(teclas, tamaño_pos_jugador_1):
    tamaño_pos_jugador_1 = list(tamaño_pos_jugador_1)
    if teclas[pygame.K_UP]:
        tamaño_pos_jugador_1[1] -= velocidad_jugadores
    if teclas[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        tamaño_pos_jugador_1[1] += velocidad_jugadores
    if teclas[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        tamaño_pos_jugador_1[0] -= velocidad_jugadores
    if teclas[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        tamaño_pos_jugador_1[0] += velocidad_jugadores
    return tuple(tamaño_pos_jugador_1)
```

Al usar la función en el bucle haremos algo parecido a:

```py
actual_pos_jugador_1 = movimiento_jugador_1(teclas, actual_pos_jugador_1)
```

Para ello antes del bucle tenemos que inicializar `actual_pos_jugador_1 = tamaño_pos_jugador_1`.
El motivo por el que tenemos que hacer algo así es que `tamaño_pos_jugador_1` es una variable global.
Si tienes interés, pídemelo en los comentarios y me extiendo más en esta explicación.

---

Sin embargo lo que yo haría es usar una lista.
Si defines tu variable global con corchetes en vez de con paréntesis tendrás un objeto mutable: `tamaño_pos_jugador_1 = [100, 100, 15, 200]`.
Ahora puedes modificar este objeto dentro de la función `movimiento_jugador_1`.
Es muy importante que no hagas `tamaño_pos_jugador_1 = list(tamaño_pos_jugador_1)`.
El motivo es que la llamada a `list` devuelve un nuevo objeto; es decir, dentro de `movimiento_jugador_1` estarías modificando un objeto que no es el que tienes fuera de la función.
Si te decides por esta opción, no tienes que modificar la llamada a la función.

Comment: Hola Jorge, gracias por su respuesta. Implementé la solución de cambiar la tupla tamaño_pos_jugador_1 por una lista y con eso todo funcionó a la perfección.